# Windows Password changed, now I can't access a TFS GIT Repository

Tags: git, authentication, tfs, active-directory

Windows Password changed, now I can't access a TFS GIT Repository.

```
C:\MyRepo>git pull
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://tfsgit.somedomain.com/Dev/_git/MyRepo/'
```

Note:

- Using git version 2.17.1.windows.2
- git config --global credential.helper manager
- git config --list --show-origin - shows that I am in fact using the credential manager.
- Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Credential Manager -> Generic Credentials - updating/changing/deleting these did nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open Internet Explorer to https://tfsgit.somedomain.com/Dev/_git/MyRepo/.
2. Authenticate with the TFS Git web application.
3. Open a command window. Re-attempt git pull

`C:\MyRepo>git pull
remote: Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) Team Foundation Server
remote: Found 1661 objects to send. (315 ms)
Receiving objects: 100% (1661/1661), 100.94 MiB | 470.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (783/783), completed with 388 local objects.`

4. The new password will be updated in Credential Manager.

Comment: Changing it in Credential Manager worked for me. There were two entries starting with `git:` for the repositry that both needed to be changed.

Comment: For me it was @jacobappleton his solution that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your git credentials from Windows Control Panel (as what everyone is suggesting)

If cmd still not prompting you for reentering of git credentials. e.g

fatal: Authentication failed for ....

You may try to uninstall your git-windows and choose the 'None' option. To avoid using a credentials helper.

[Select None for Git-Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NO53g.png)